# Facebook Graph API only returns user name

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was using Facebook's graph api, asking for '/me', and it only returns the name and Id of the user. I know that it logs in properly, because it returns the correct name.

Here is a snippet of the javascript code I was using:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    // handle the response
    FB.api('/me', function (usrresponse) {
        document.getElementById('inFbStatus').innerHTML = 'Successful login to Facebook';
        console.log(JSON.stringify(usrresponse));
    });
}, { scope: 'email, basic_info' });
```

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: You have to specify the fields that you want back

Comment: I am missing the user's email and the url of their profile, even though I specified 'email' in the scope.

Comment: That most likely means your app is using API v2.4 – the changelog explains what has changed in that regard, so go read it please: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify each field and edge you want to get returned, e. g.

```
/me?fields=id,name,email
```