# user_id/scores only returns the user object facebook graph api

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, leaderboard

I'm trying to create a facebook leaderboard for my game. I've read their tutorial ( [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial) ). However it seems like that is using another version of the api.
I'm using the graph api, thanks to looking at the documentation and around the net I created this:

```
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            //First get the users ID
            "/me",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback(){
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response){
                    Log.e("GET", "facebookresponse: " + response.toString());
                    try{
                        JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                        userID = json.getLong("id");
                        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                //Then get the score
                                "/" + userID + "/scores",
                                null,
                                HttpMethod.GET,
                                new GraphRequest.Callback(){
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response1){
                                        Log.e("GET", response1.toString());
                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e("GET", "JSONException: " +  e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

In order to get the score of a player. However I only get a JSONArray of users (with the size of 1 but I presume that is because I'm only testing on one user currently)

I tried adding `?fields=id,name,email,score` as according to this StackOverflow question: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600821/facebook-graph-api-only-returns-user-name), I only got a 2500 error code from that (wrong end of line).

Here's the code I've used to post the score for that user:

```
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback(){
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response){
                    Log.e("GET", "facebookresponse: " + response.toString());
                    try{
                        JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                        userID = json.getLong("id");
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putInt("score", 21);
                        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                "/" + userID + "/scores",
                                params,
                                HttpMethod.POST,
                                new GraphRequest.Callback(){
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                        Log.e("GET", "post respose: " + response.toString());
                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e("GET", "JSONException: " +  e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

The response when I do that graphRequest is success:true.
So apparently that one works.

I'm completely lost right now and in desperate need of some help, I've not really managed to find any help on the internet aside from the documentation, the pages mentioned above and the occassional tutorial for the wrong version.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried making the request include the fields you want? `"/" + userID + "/scores?fields=user,score"`

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, this is the error I get when I do that:    `Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Syntax error "Expected end of string instead of "?"." at character 10: user,score?access_token{access_token}`

Comment: Then try and pass `fields` as a parameter in the method call, with value `user,score`.

Comment: @CBroe Of course! That solved it! Thank you very much!